# Assigning a value to an @Input property without using a binding?

Tags: angular, typescript

If we have an angular component with an `@Input() name: string` property, and we just want to set the property directly without binding the property from the parent do we just do `<custom-component name="Rick Jones"></custom-component>`?

So in other words we just set the `name` property like we would any other property on normal html elements.

Comment: yes you can !!!

Comment: Isn't it `@Input() name: string` ?

Comment: Fixed it - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can hardcode it like you have:

```
<custom-component name="Rick Jones"></custom-component>
```

Square brackets are only needed when you bind it to a property in your model. The above is equivalent to the following property binding:

```
<custom-component [name]="'Rick Jones'"></custom-component>
```